# No setea el valor de un input con VueJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

Tengo un input text con typeahead que uso para buscar un usuario

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto lo hago mediante un componente de vue, el template es:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <label for="">Buscar Usuario</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control search-user" required="" placeholder="Usuario" autocomplete="off"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="id_user" required="" v-model="user"/>
    </div>
</template>


<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            user: ''
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        $('.search-user').typeahead({
            source: function (query, result) {
                return $.post("/FinDraT/users/getUsersTypeAhead", {query: query}, function (data) {
                    return result(data);
                });
            },
            updater: function (item) {
               this.user = item.id;

                return item;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

El problema es que al seleccionar el usuario, en el método updater quiero setear el id en el input hidden que después lo uso para guardar el usuario en el modelo que me encuentro.

El input hidden probe con v-model:"user", :value="user" y ninguno me setea el valor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es el `scope` de javascript en el cual trabajas.

Al momento de usar `function` el código que se ejecutará en esa función tendrá su propio `scope`, que es diferente al entorno, para darte un ejemplo, esto es lo que se hacía antes:

```
function () {
    // main scope
    var self = this;
    function () {
        // second scope
        self === this; // false
        // como te das cuenta, aquí this es otro objeto
    }
}
```

Por este motivo no te funciona, para eso se crearon las `arrow functions`, las cuales nos permiten mantener el `scope` de la siguiente forma:

```
function () {
    var self = this;
    () => {
        self === this; // true
    }
}
```

> ESTOS EJEMPLOS SON DEMOSTRATIVOS

Para tu caso, aplicaría de la siguiente forma:

```
mounted() {
    $('.search-user').typeahead({
        source: function (query, result) {
            return $.post("/FinDraT/users/getUsersTypeAhead", {query: query}, function (data) {
                return result(data);
            });
        },
        updater: (item) {
            this.user = item.id;
            return item;
        }
    });
}
```

Espero haberte ayudado.

Answer (score 0):

Probablemente se deba a que no existe la función `updater` en la versión de typeahead.js que estas usando.
Bootstrap recomiendo utilizar https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js en su lugar.

Reemplazando a `updater` está `typeahead:selected`, se utiliza de la siguiente manera.

```
$('.search-user').typeahead({
  source: function (query, result) {
    return $.post("/FinDraT/users/getUsersTypeAhead", {query: query}, function (data) {
      return result(data);
    });
  }
})
.on('typeahead:selected', function(e, item) {
  this.user = item
});
```

Comment: Seguramente esta respuesta tampoco funcionará, ten en cuenta el scope en el cual estas trabajando, estas dentro de `mounted()` y al entrar al evento `typeahead:select` estás cambiando de scope, por lo cuál `this` deja de ser el objeto de vue, para solucionarlo usa arrow functions en su lugar

Comment: Es como dice @GermanAlzate, no tuve en cuenta que estaba adentro del typeahead

Comment: Lo anotare como respuesta